# Recommendations on best-value stock fixed gear model?

Tags: fixed-gear, commuting-bike, utility-cycling

I am looking for a decent fixed gear model. My whole cycling background is on Mountain Biking, so I don't want to build a fixie with spare parts or convert.
I am looking at some out of the box whole bikes, like Surly Steamroller (which I suspect is a bit heavy), GT Gutterball (which perhaps might be too attractive to thieves) and others (which might be to expensive).

My goal is to have a light (less than 20lb) steel beater which I can lock anywhere with no worries and forget about maintenance.

EDIT: My target price would be around $700 to $1000 brand new, which could give me a nicer used bike, or a cheaper semi-new bike.

Comment: Can you give us an idea of your budget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your looking for a "beater" fixie that you don't have to worry about getting stolen and maintaining, it might be worth checking out Craigslist. I see fixies come up every couple days in my area.  IMO, its not worth spending the $ on a brand new bike to be your beater bike.

If you want something brand new, Redline makes some nice bikes that are usually a tad cheaper than the competition. They make the [Urbis](http://www.redlinebicycles.com/bikes/commute/2012-urbis) which I think is around $750 or so, which I think is close to the Steamroller in price, but has a disc brake (which I suppose might make it more attractive to thieves, but does add value for the price). No idea on weights though, since manufacturers rarely publish them.

What kind of budget are you looking at here ("too expensive" is a very relative term)?

Comment: It would be around $700, and the Steamroller is around that price. Also, I would not mind much to put a brand new bike to work as a beater, because beaters have "style" ;oP. Thanks for answering and for the Craigslist tip!

Answer (score 0):

My first and so far only fixed gear was the [KHS Flite 100](http://khsbicycles.com/05_flite_100_08.htm), which I got for about $500.  Let me say I LOVE that bike, and I still ride it today. It comes with everything you need, it's super light, quick, and responsive, just very very fun all around.

After about I year here's some things I upgraded... I put some studded platform pedals on it with some [Burro foot straps](http://www.burrobags.com/products/chronic-pedal-straps).